# Attempting to use pools crashes Celluloid

Tags: ruby, threadpool, jruby, celluloid

I'm trying to use pools in a project of mine that uses Celluloid. However, whenever I invoke the `pool` method on a class which `include`s Celluloid (thus receiving methods from `Celluloid::ClassMethods`) I consistently get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `services' for Celluloid:Module
     router at /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0/gems/celluloid-supervision-0.20.6/lib/celluloid/supervision/deprecate/supervise.rb:54
  supervise at /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0/gems/celluloid-supervision-0.20.6/lib/celluloid/supervision/deprecate/supervise.rb:6
       pool at /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0/gems/celluloid-pool-0.20.5/lib/celluloid/supervision/container/behavior/pool.rb:13
      <top> at celluloid_pool_test.rb:14
```

Specifically, this part seems to be the problem:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `services' for Celluloid:Module

It tells me that the offending line is `/Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0/gems/celluloid-supervision-0.20.6/lib/celluloid/supervision/deprecate/supervise.rb:54`. It turns out that line holds the code for the `Celluloid::Supervision.router` method:

```
def router(*_args)
  # TODO: Actually route, based on :branch, if present; or else:
  Celluloid.services ### this line is what causes the error
end
```

To make sure that the issue wasn't with my particular project, I grabbed a code sample from [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-celluloid-part-ii/) which utilizes pools and tried to run it:

```
require 'celluloid'
require 'mathn'

class PrimeWorker
  include Celluloid

  def prime(number)
    if number.prime?
      puts number
    end
  end  
end

pool = PrimeWorker.pool

(2..1000).to_a.map do |i|
  pool.prime! i
end

sleep 100
```

It failed with the exact same error as my project:

Finally, I ran a dead simple piece of code in IRB to see if `pool` is what triggers the error about `services`:

```
class Foo
  include Celluloid
end
Foo.pool
```

Sure enough, I got the exact same error. It seems that there is a bug in Celluloid or that I'm not loading a dependency properly. However, I did `require 'celluloid/supervision'` in my attempts at solving this, to no avail. Am I doing something wrong on my end or is this a bug in Celluloid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that others have run into this issue before: https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid-pool/issues/10. I guess it has something to do with `Celluloid.services` being deprecated and not working in newer versions of Celluloid, so using `require 'celluloid/current'` rather than just `require 'celluloid'` seems to do the trick.